# Swift - removeAllAnimations() - One animation after the other

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

So I animated a button to move to a specific point (`CGPoint`) on the screen when the view loads. I also added a swipeGestureRecogniser to make it that if the user swipes left, than the animation will stop and a new one will start that takes the button to a different CGPoint. I did this by calling the `removeAllAnimations()` method on the button. The problem is that when the user swipes left, the button finishes the first animation without animating. So it doesn't stop and start the new animation, but rather it jumps to the end of the first animation and then continues to the next animation. Is there a way to stop the first animation and seamlessly start the next?

This is the code:

[image: Code]

Comment: add some delay between two animations

Comment: I think it's because you're using UIView animation, removeAllAnimations only worked with the CALayer animation. So if you add these animation as CALayer, swipeLeft gesture will remove all animations.

Answer (score 1):

It's working as expected. At the time you call `removeAllAnimations()`, there's only one animation to be removed - the second one will be added in first's completion block. So instead of nesting animations, you can try something like that:

```
// first animation
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: { /... }, completion: { //... })
// second animation
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 5, animations: { /... })
```